# Executed Bashscript alters command

Tags: linux, bash

Im using Bashscript for automated backups from my system and most important config files.

Strange thing is, after running the script it should send me an email with content of a log file. But debugging the script  reveals, that it runs an altered command than written in my script

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
###########################
###                     ###
###     BACKUP SCRIPT   ###
###                     ###
###########################
......
LOG="backup.log"
exec > >(tee -i >( sed 's/\x1B\[[0-9;]*[JKmsu]//g' > ${LOG}))
exec 2>&1

# commands etc

mailx -s "Backup | subject" mail@mail.tld < $LOG
```

So my log contains all necessary output and isn't empty.

Debugging the script reveals this

```
echo -e '\033[1;32mExiting prune script\033[0m'
Exiting prune script
+ mailx -s 'Backup | subject' mail@mail.tld #Missing < $LOG!!!
```

Really dunno why it's missing my logfile. The mail I receive ist just an empty mail with correct subject.

Some ideas why?

PS: using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but this shouldn't matter

Backup.log: https://pastebin.com/cCVSLV0h nothing special.

If I run mail command directly from my shell it sends this log as I expect it.

Comment: That's the usual debug output. If backup.log does not exist, you will get an additional error message.

Comment: But why it's not sending my logfile. It exists, isn't empty. I can access it right before sending the mail without any problem

Comment: Upload backup.log somewhere and add a link to your question.

Comment: added pastebin link